# How do you obtain Wool Beanies for Chao?

Tags: sonic-adventure-2-battle

I'm trying to find out how to get the wool beanie for chao, any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot I'm actually not even sure thats a beanie, you may be mistaking its head for a hat. However, all things are aquired at the Black Market in the Chao School by obtaining emblems to unlock the item and then spending rings to buy it. If your Black Market does not sell what you want, get more emblems and come back.

Comment: +1 Not sure why this was never accepted, but that is either the Black or Blue Wool Beanie, which sells for either 10,000 or 20,000 (respectively).  It is hard to tell which one it is because of the image quality, but the Black Market is the place to get it.

Comment: @hyper thanks, it happens a lot with what I refer to as 'flash users', they come, they ask a question, they leave. It's the nature of the beast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found it helpful. This picture is not my screenshot, found it on Google images. Also, that is a black wool beanie to the left.